# print msgid msgstr from po file to another file

Tags: translation, po

I have a translated .po file. I like to extract msgid and msgstr to another file.. so that i can print it and give it for error checking to another person..

Here i need omit all the strings/newline/whitespace and space characters. i need only lines with msgid and msgstr

example input

**

```
#: ../src/administration-activity/admin/class_edit.py:56 
msgid "Editing a Class" 
msgstr "ತರಗತಿನ್ನು  ಬದಲಾಯಿಸಲಾಗುತ್ತಿದೆ" 

#: ../src/administration-activity/admin/class_edit.py:61 
msgid "Editing class: " 
msgstr "ಬದಲಾಯಿಲಾಗುತ್ತಿರುವ ತರಗ:"
```

**

required output

```
    msgid "Editing a Class" 
    msgstr "ತರಗತಿನ್ನು  ಬದಲಾಯಿಸಲಾಗುತ್ತಿದೆ" 
    msgid "Editing class: " 
    msgstr "ಬದಲಾಯಿಲಾಗುತ್ತಿರುವ ತರಗ:"
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Eazy Po](http://www.eazypo.ca) you  use Export Using Template to save the file the way you like. Open the po file, and from the File menu select Export -> Using Template. A Template Editor window will pop up:

[image]

In the left pane list right click for a popup menu and select New Template. In New Template dialog define your template name and press Ok.

[image]

In the Loop Block text box type the following (or copy & paste):

```
msgid "%source%"
msgstr "%translation%"
```

You will notice a sample result in the Result Example pane at the bottom of the window and this result will change instantly as you play with it.

[image]

Select Generate & Save button to save the generated file. 
For escape characters substitution; see the setting for the other pre built templates.